# SAPUI5 Deep Insert from Kapsel Offline App on OData V2 Model

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

**Question:**

How can a "Deep Insert" performed from a SAPUI5 Client application on an OData V2 Model?

**Situation:**

I want to Deep Insert an "Operation" together with some "Components" into my OData V2 Model in my SAPUI5 Client application.

```
 // the request data
 "OperationSet" : {         
          "Orderid" : "13700090",       
          "OperationComponentSet" : [
              {                
                "Orderid" : "13700090",
                "Activity" : "0010",
                "SubActivity" : "",
                "ComponentItem" : "000010"                 
              }
            ]
}

this.getView().getModel().create("/OperationSet", requestData);
```

I cannot use  the function *create(sPath, oData, mParameters?)* on the OData V2 Model the documentation says: "Please note that deep creates are not supported and may not work." see https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#create

Is there any other possibility to perform a Deep Insert on an OData V2 Model?

**Links:**

- https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html
- http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58063#deepinsert

Comment: The same comment you can find at the ODataModel, but I was able to do a deep insert as the backend service supported it. Thus it should work if your backend supports it.

Comment: It doesn't work.The create_entity method is only called and not the create_deep_entity

Comment: Please post the line where you call create. I assume that "not supported" does not mean that you can't send an entity to a backend service manually.

Comment: @matbtt:  what do mean "manually"? Will it be the official/standard way to do it?

Comment: It works with the create() method if the request is done directly online against the gateway. the request data structure (array with name of navigation attribute inside header data) dictates if CREATE_ENTITIY or CREATE_DEEP_ENTITY is called. It doesn't work in an Offline App for me http://scn.sap.com/thread/3708673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, "Deep Insert" doesn't support 0..n assoziations with the Offline Kapsel Plugin at the moment.

see http://help.sap.com/saphelp_smp308sdk/helpdata/en/d3/0ded03756247f1a136c84be7901879/content.htm

> Limitations of Deep Inserts A deep insert is an OData POST request to
>   create an entity that also contains the inlined definitions of related
>   entities.
>
> When a deep insert is processed, the top-level entity and all of its
>   related entities are created and linked together as a single
>   operation. In SDK SP07, the Offline Store supports deep inserts
>   through the OData API on Android, iOS and WinPhone 8 platforms with
>   one important restriction:
>
> - The navigation property used for the deep insert must refer to at most one entity. Any inlined related entities must be added using a
>     navigation property whose ToRole refers to an association end with
>     cardinality 0..1 or 1. They cannot be added using a navigation
>     property whose ToRole refers to an association end with cardinality *.
>     Navigation properties that refer to a set of entities cannot be used
>     for deep inserts.

So "Deep Insert" will only work if the request is executed online against the gateway at the moment.

Comment: An alternative solution can be "Content ID Referencing" see http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-65397